# Xcode 10.2 fails local commit with "Multiple working copies failed to commit files"

Tags: git, xcode, commit

After Xcode updating to 10.2, the local commit fails with message 
"Multiple working copies failed to commit files"

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

A thing I did between commits is that I updated the Pods, I wonder if this can have something to do with the issue, there are now 791 files waiting for commit.

All help highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Reason & solution found:

Xcode bug, author details are deleted when Xcode is updated, the following from cmd line in the workspace dir fixes the problem:

```
xcrun git config user.name "your_user_name"
xcrun git config user.email your_email
```

After running the commands, restart Xcode

Answer (score 2):

What Kristian H has answered is correct and same can be achieved within Xcode IDE itself:

Xcode -> Preferences -> Source Control [tab] -> Git [tab] and filling missing details.

This avoids opening command line and reopening your Xcode.

Comment: They can be set there but probably due to a bug in Xcode, they don't persist in the fields. When you close preferences and open it up again, the fields are empty although you just filled them. Closing Xcode and doing it in cmd makes them persist.

Comment: I think it does persist once it is added on. Maybe you have something else going on there. On Xcode 10.2 (10e125) the fix worked perfectly fine with Xcode IDE, and it persists. May be others can tell which one works and which one does not :)

Comment: Hmm, the behaviour might have changed during new updates, will have to check next time they disappear. I'd assume the same thing is making them not persist via the GUI that makes the fields go empty in the first place.